# maximizing entropy -> solving the dual problem analytically

Tags: exponential-function, machine-learning, lagrange-multiplier, entropy

I have to maximize entropy and therefore formulated the dual function, calculated its derivatives, set them equal to zero and now I have to solve the following system **analytically**:

$$
e^{-\mu_1 - \mu_2} + e^{-\mu_1 - 2\mu_2} + e^{-\mu_1 - 3\mu_2} + e^{-\mu_1 - 4\mu_2} = e^{1} \\
e^{-\mu_1 - \mu_2} + 2e^{-\mu_1 - 2\mu_2} + 3e^{-\mu_1 - 3\mu_2} + 4e^{-\mu_1 - 4\mu_2} = e^{1} 
$$

I tried all kind of stuff but that didnt work out so far.

How can I solve this system analytically?

Comment: If you don't want mathematica to do the work for you, you can let $x = e^{-\mu_1}$ and $y = e^{-\mu_2}$. Then you end up with the equations:

$$xy + xy^2 + x y^3 + x y^4 = e,$$
$$xy + 2xy^2 + 3 y^3 + 4 x y^4 = e$$

with $x,y \ne 0$ (as exponentials never vanish). Now you can solve for $x$ in terms of $y$ in the first equation, and get an equation for $y$ from the second. In particular, you get $1 + 2 y + 3 y^2 = 0$ and then $x$ is given explicitly in terms of $y$. Given a solution $(x_0,y_0)$, then $(\mu_1,\mu_2) = (\log(x_0),\log(y_0)) + (2 \pi i \mathbf{Z},2 \pi i \mathbf{Z})$.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica gives this solutions:

$c_1,c_2\in \mathbb{Z}$

$
   \left\{\mu_1=2 i \pi  c_1+\log \left(-\frac{4 i
   \left(4 \sqrt{2}-7 i\right)}{81
   e}\right),\mu_2=2 i \pi  c_2+\log \left(i
   \left(\sqrt{2}+i\right)\right)\right\}$

OR

$
   \left\{\mu_1= 2 i \pi  c_1+\log \left(\frac{4 i
   \left(4 \sqrt{2}+7 i\right)}{81
   e}\right),\mu_2=2 i \pi  c_2+\log \left(-i
   \left(\sqrt{2}-i\right)\right)\right\}$